# Как задать стиль для стандартного ListPreference?

Tags: java, android

```
<ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:dialogTitle="dialogTitle"
        android:entries="@array/entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/entryValues"
        android:key="key"
        android:title="@string/Title" />
```

Comment: Ответ можно найти примерно за 13 секунд в гугле. По запросу `android listpreference style`

Comment: Google рулит! Жаль только я искал в яндексе, хотя по тому же запросу!

Comment: Я может вас удивлю, но в гугле можно найти ответы на 98% задаваемых тут вопросов, потратив не более 30 секунд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<com.your.domain.ThemedListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/select_type"
        android:entries="@array/pref_secur_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_secur_values"
        android:key="key"
        android:theme="@style/ListPreferenceTheme"
        android:title="Title" />
```

Создайте новый класс, к примеру ThemedListPreference:

```
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.ListPreference;

public class ThemedListPreference extends ListPreference {
private static int[] ATTRS = { android.R.attr.theme };
private ContextThemeWrapper mContextWrapper;


public ThemedListPreference(Context context){
    this(context, null);
}

public ThemedListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ATTRS);
    mContextWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, a.getResourceId(0, 0));
    a.recycle();
}

@Override
public Context getContext(){
    return mContextWrapper;
  }
}
```

Добавьте в style.xml:

```
<style name="ListPreferenceTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```